# EditText saved in SharedPref with price formated

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have one EditText with a price like $15, or 15€. It depend of the currency of your phone.
The problem is, when I change the text of my EditText, I would like to save only the decimal in my SharedPreference but I would like to set the text of my EditText again like this : $15 or 15€ for example.
For that, maybe I should make editable only the decimal and not the currency. But I don't know how to do that.

For the moment, I have that :

```
editTextPrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String price = editable.toString().replaceAll("\\D+",""); // take only decimal for the price
                Preferences.setPrice(getContext(), price);
                editTextPrice.setText(Format.formatPrice(price));
            }
        });
```

The problem with this solution is the setText in my afterTextChanger. It make me an infinite loop because it's always changing my text.

Maybe this is not the solution. Maybe I only have to put the currency on the left or the right on make editable the decimal. But  don't know how can I do that.

I'm a little lost :/

Thanks.

Comment: Basically you need the currency to be displayed at left and the user can insert currency value right?

Comment: It depend. For example : if your currency is dollar, it's in the left. For euros, it's on the right.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent infinite loop You can add variable-flag, like this:

```
editTextPrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            boolean ignoreChange = false;

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (!ignoreChange) {
                    String price = editable.toString().replaceAll("\\D+",""); // take only decimal for the price
                    Preferences.setPrice(getContext(), price);
                    ignoreChange = true;
                    editTextPrice.setText(Format.formatPrice(price));
                    ignoreChange = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

than check it in `afterTextChanged(Editable editable)`, surround `editTextPrice` changes with `ignoreChange = true;` ... `ignoreChange = false;` and do your magic with $ or €.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be quite simple. Assuming you have the currency saved in the variable `currency`, simply get the content of EditText using

```
String content = et.getText().toString()
```

Then, when you want to save the value, without the currency, use `replace(oldChar,newChar)` and replace the currency with an empty string.

```
String value = content.replace(currency,"");
```

You'll have your double or integer value and you can save it to SharedPreferences.